# Javascript Code is not working!

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, validation

Whenever I am writing a javascript code to check if the input text is taking an empty value, it doesn't work. Please check what is the problem with my code?

[image: Page Code]
[Page Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R53fg.png)

[image: Controller Code]

Comment: Hi Happy, thanks for posting your code - it makes it a lot easier to help you!  Next time, please copy and paste the code rather than uploading a screenshot - it's easier to read and allows search engines to index its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Open the page in your web browser and inspect (Right click > Inspect Element) the text input field.  You'll find that its ID is not `name`, but something in the format of `Parent1:Parent2:name`.

This is because Salesforce does not simply output the ID given for the element in the Visualforce file, but also includes the names of element's parents, from outermost (here the `apex:page`) inwards. As a result, `document.getElementsById('name')` is failing to select the element.

To fix this, have a look at [this post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/component-vs-selectors.html) by the wonderful "Uncle" Bob Buzzard, aka Keir Bowden, aka Walter Sobchak.  In short, you need to add `id` attributes to your Visualforce components and change the Javascript selector to use the format `{!Component.PageName.FormName.PageblockName.InputTextName}`.

Alternatively you could use a selector library such as the one in jQuery, but it looks like it would be overkill for this use case.